# Can Retrofit Parse Boolean Out of Box?

Tags: android, boolean, retrofit

I want to know can Retrofit parse boolean out-of-box ? or it need a custom converter and what server must pass to it ? ( 0 or 1 | True or False ) ?

Interface :

```
 Call<Boolean> IABValidate(.......);
```

Comment: did you find out the solution?